# php go to random links how to?

Tags: php, random

i have a link:

```
<a href="">Click Me!</a>
```

and i have a few links: `google.com`, `yahoo.com`, etc...

what i want is each time i click on the `Click Me!` to grab a random link and go to it

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand) to pick out a random item from an array:

```
$urls = array('http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com');
echo '<a href="' . $urls[array_rand($urls)] . '">Click Me!</a>';
```